# Bind ComboBox#itemsProperty to Map#keySet

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

For what I am doing, I need to set the members of a `javafx.scene.control.ComboBox` to the members of a `Map#keySet()` Set.

The options available in the ComboBox need to update as the keys of the Map are updated. (Basically, I want to use the ComboBox to select members from the Map, which WILL be updated at runtime.)

Unfortunately, neither `ComboBox#itemsProperty().bind(ObservableValue<>)` nor `ComboBox#itemsProperty().set(ObservableList<>)` will take a Set<>, so the direct route of connecting the itemsProperty to the `Map#keySet` doesn't work.

Basically:
How can I make it so the ComboBox's items are the members of a Map's keySet?
Again, the behavior that I need is that the `ComboBox`'s items will reflect the `KeySet` of my `Map`. (The `Map` can be any implementation of `Map`.)

EDIT: The problem seems to be creating an `ObservableList` out of a `Collection` -- in this case a `Set` -- without making it just a copy, but rather a reference to the `Set`, in order that the `ObservableList` will reflect the `Set`'s contents.

Comment: Can you use an `ObservableMap` as the `Map`?

Comment: Yes, the `Map` can be an `ObservableMap`. However, to `bind` or `set` the itemsProperty to an `ObservableList`; I need to have an `ObservableList`.

Comment: You can either add a listener to the `ObservableMap`, or create a custom binding. See answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an `ObservableMap`, you can add a listener to it. For example:

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = ... ;
ObservableMap<String, Something> map = ... ;
map.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Something> c) -> 
    comboBox.getItems().setAll(map.keySet()));
```

You can also do this with a binding, though I don't think it's any cleaner:

```
comboBox.itemsProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.keySet()),
    map);
```

Here's a SSCCE, demonstrating both techniques:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BindItemsToKeySet extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableMap<Integer, Item> itemLookupById = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
        ComboBox<Integer> listenerCombo = new ComboBox<>();
        ComboBox<Integer> bindingCombo = new ComboBox<>();

        itemLookupById.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer, ? extends Item> c) -> 
            listenerCombo.getItems().setAll(itemLookupById.keySet())
        );

        bindingCombo.itemsProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(itemLookupById.keySet()), 
            itemLookupById));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                return ;
            }
            Item item = new Item(textField.getText());
            itemLookupById.put(item.getId(), item);
            textField.clear();
        });

        textField.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Type an item name and press enter"));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, 
                textField, 
                listenerCombo, 
                bindingCombo);

        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 350));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static class Item {
        private final int id ;
        private final String name ;

        private final static AtomicInteger nextID = new AtomicInteger(1000);

        public Item(String name) {
            this.id = nextID.incrementAndGet();
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong but the first one (adding the ComboBox as a Listener for the ObservableMap.

However, I was able to get the binding to work. Thanks!

Comment: I typed it directly here without testing, so there may be errors. I'll check when I get a chance.

Comment: Yup, I had the type parameters for the `Change` wrong. Fixed and added an example.

Comment: Great solution!